# All image pixel values become 205 after setting CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH and CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT in OpenCV using webcam

Tags: windows, opencv, visual-studio-2017, webcam

I use a webcam with default resolution of 640x480, the environment is OpenCV 4.0, visual studio 17 and win10. If I read directly from webcam everything is fine, but after I set CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH and CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, I can still get image from webcam but all pixel values become (205,205,205). The code is simple:

```
VideoCapture cap(0);
cap.set(CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 320);
cap.set(CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 240);
Mat img;
cap.read(img);
```

What might cause the problem? Thank you!

Comment: seems like a bug, you can file an issue [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/)